# How to get manually fully qualified class name in the spring configuration file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

how we could get manually fully qualified class name in the spring configuration file for exp:

Define Spring MVC view resolver

class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"

For Setup Hibernate session factory

class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"

These things how we could get manually in eclipse bcoz we have added spring jars and hibernate jars in the lib folder how I could get manually from eclipse through spring jars that procedure I want.
I don't want to use the internet, on the internet this things are there.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain better what are you trying to achieve. Do you want to have a way for Eclipse to show you the names of classes that you can use for configuration in your Spring project?

Comment: Search for the class in your eclipse `Package Explorer`. Select the class, right click it and choose `Copy Qualified Name`.